# Access Violation while calling sysutils.now()

Tags: delphi

One of our client reporting accessviolation which is not easily reproducible. We have provided logging mechanism. While checking in the logs, we noticed the AV is coming from entirely different different operations. Sometimes freeing an object, sometimes while creating object and some time while calling sysutils.now() and many other operations too.

we are puzzled with this and while working on this one of our developer machine also raised an accessviolation from sysutils.now()

Please note this is not reproducible. But if we consider a period of time our client is getting accessviolations frequently.

we are using eureka logs for logging purpose. Issue happend on xp machines.

Other programs installed on the machines are

Windows XP SP3,
      Office 2007,
      Winzip,
      SAP,
      Symantec antivirus and update agent,
      Altiris Client,
      Cisco VPN client &
      our delphi program.

any help or hints would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Basil

Comment: It's extremely unlikely the error is in sysutils.now(). That function is just a thin wrapper around `kernel32.dll -> GetLocalTime`  If Kernel32 has an issue, your client's computer will stop working **real fast**. If you can supply some source code (preferably the part where your developer got the AV that would help). **As it stands your question is unanswerable**

Answer (score 2):

You should use FastMM4 within your project (i believe this is actually part of more recent Delphi versions).  FastMM4 will catch leaks and violations that occur.  You are probably suffering from a storage corruption that is only detected by its impact upon other functions.

FastMM4 has lots of settings so read the documentation

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/

BTW, It's free.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were wondering, here's the source code for `now()`

```
function Now: TDateTime;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
var
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetLocalTime(SystemTime);
  with SystemTime do
    Result := EncodeDate(wYear, wMonth, wDay) +
      EncodeTime(wHour, wMinute, wSecond, wMilliseconds);
end;
{$ENDIF}
....
procedure GetLocalTime; external kernel32 name 'GetLocalTime';
....
```

**Use madexcept**
Your error surely is not there. The solution is to add debug info to your application.
I warmly recommend buying `MadExcept` (free for non-commercial use) :
http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm

It will give you a detailed stacktrace (in human readable form) that you can log to a file (or that will be emailed to you automatically).
In most cases this will give you the info you need to track down the cause of the issue.
Note that with madexcept (fully) enabled you application will run slow as hell, so I suggest you supply the client with two versions so they don't have to suffer the slowness all the time.

Comment: thanks for reviewing. i agreed with you, we are also got the error only once. Is there any thing to suspect with the antivirus? can an antivirus play the memory location of a program ? we have the call stacks provided by eureka log just like madexcept, both are similar. all the same code working fine for other clients. thats why we wonder and puzzled.

Comment: i cannot copy the callstack here because of its size. how can i attach it in a file ?

Comment: Don't attach it in a file. Use a service like pastebin.com. But if the call stack is really so big that Stack Overflow won't let you paste it here, you've got other problems, like maybe unbounded recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted without some source code and some more background it may be hard to answer this question to your satisfaction.

One thing to note: If its happening when freeing an object the object may have already been freed. This can easily happen if you are mixing manual object clean up with reference counted interfaces.

- If the object is freed before the interface refcount reaches zero an AV will
  occur whenever the next interface reference goes out of scope or the interface reference is set to `nil`.
- If the interface refcount reaches zero first it will be automatically freed. If later the object is then manually freed an AV will occur because `Free` is an instance method and the instance no longer exists.

I also think the SysUtil.Now() may be a red herring. Its more likely the logger is getting confused by memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

When an API as simple as Sysutils.Now start crashing, I would start looking for buffer overruns. This is often the most likely culprit.

If this is the situation, callstack will prove pretty much useless at find the source of the problem.  I believe AQTime has a tool that allows to trace this kind of problem, but I never used it for that purpose.